# list all the files with the same extension as specified by the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files. The first argument will be the path to the directory we want to filter on, and the second argument, the type of the file that we need to print,

we must use readdir function .

like running this:

```
node fileJS.js   /Users/admin/Desktop  .docx
```

I've tried this code, but it will no return anything, for some reason.

can you please help me

```
var fs = require('fs');  //require node filesystem module
var path = require('path'); //require node path module (a couple of tools for reading path names)

var pathSupplied = process.argv[2];
var extFilter = process.argv[3];

function extension(element) {
  var extName = path.extname(element);
  return extName === '.' + extFilter; 
};

fs.readdir(pathSupplied, function(err, list) {
  list.filter(extension).forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

Comment: invoke your current script just changing your last argument by `docx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you provide the extension argument starting with a `.` because in your filter function (`extension`) you are adding another dot when comparing (line: `return extName === '.' + extFilter;`).

Just invoke your current script like this:

```
node fileJS.js   /Users/admin/Desktop  docx
```

Or update your filter function to assume `extFilter` is provided with a starting dot.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the command like this:

```
node fileJS.js   /Users/admin/Desktop  docx
```

...without the dot in front of the extension you're looking for. Your code works then, I just tested it.